# What complex function is holomorphic in z = -i but not conformal in this point?

Tags: complex-analysis

What complex function is holomorphic in $z = -i$ but not conformal in this point?

Comment: Pick one from many...

Comment: A constant would be an example.

Comment: All of you here, thank you for helping !

Comment: You just need that $f'(i)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest nontrivial one is $(z+i)^2$. It's holomorphic (I've just given you the series expansion around $z=-i$), but any angle in that point gets doubled, and thus it's not conformal.

Answer (score 1):

A function of form $f(z) = \alpha + (z+i)^2 \cdot g(z)$